# Cannot get TextBlock to word wrap inside a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, silverlight

I am having trouble getting the text in a TextBlock to wrap. The TextBlock is inside a Grid, which is part of a ListBoxItem template. Below is my XAML:

```
  <ListBox Grid.Row="2" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="600" Width="600" Name="lb_TestResults" ItemsSource="{Binding Test}" Margin="5,5,5,5">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Padding="4">
                    <Grid Width="auto">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Name="tb_nameLabel" Margin ="0, 0, 3, 0" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"><Bold>Test: </Bold></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Name="tb_Name" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Name="tb_descLabel" Margin="0, 0, 3, 0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"><Bold>Description: </Bold></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Name="tb_Description" Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Name="tb_statusLabel" Margin="0, 0, 3, 0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"><Bold>Status: </Bold></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Name="tb_Status" Text="{Binding Status}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Name="tb_resultLabel" Margin="0, 0, 3, 0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"><Bold>Result: </Bold></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Name="tb_Result" Text="{Binding Result}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I originally had the TextBlocks inside StackPanels, but reading various other questions on this topic such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397257/force-textblock-to-wrap-in-wpf-listbox), I decided to change it to a Grid. I only need the TextBlock `tb_Description` to word wrap. Right now the output looks like this:

[image: current]

As you can see the text is not wrapping.

I have tried setting the width explicitly on the TextBlocks, the Grid columns, and the ListBox, but nothing has helped so far. I also disabled the horizontal scrollbar, the scrollbar is gone now but the text is still trailing off the edge. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you must set the 2nd column to * so it stretches and you have swapped the TextBlock that should wrap, just a "typo" :)

#### Change

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>   

 <!-- And these here you have set the wrong textblock to wrap =) -->
<TextBlock Name="tb_descLabel" Margin="0, 0, 3, 0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"><Bold>Description: </Bold></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Name="tb_Description" Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ></TextBlock>
```

#### To

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<!-- ..... -->

<TextBlock Name="tb_descLabel" Margin="0, 0, 3, 0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"><Bold>Description: </Bold></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Name="tb_Description" Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
```

#### Result

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with the `ListBox` but with the `Grid` you are using to align text blocks. Both columns are set to `Auto` which results in `Grid` allowing columns to occupy all space their content requests for.

You need to set `Width` of the second `ColumnDefinition` to `*`:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Welp, just realized I was wrapping the label "Description" instead of the actual description text which needed wrapping. Headdesk. Your fix actually does work, though. Thank you!